# ES6 Get default parameters/arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-arguments

How can I get the value of the default parameters/arguments dynamicly without using the parameter variable?

```
function someFunc(param1 = 'value', param2 = 'value') {
    console.log(arguments.length);
    console.log(arguments[0]);
}

someFunc(); //0 undefined
```

Comment: I smell an XY Problem. What are you trying to do exactly? Why do you need to read the default values inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to do the same, in order to assign several attributes to the instance of my class.

This approach might not help you since it uses one *object* argument instead of two arguments, still worth to mention:

```
class MyClass{
  constructor(params={param1:3.1415, param2:'Hello'}){
    //*assign* effectively destructures the params arg
    Ojbect.assign(this,params);
  }
}
```

Similarly your example would look like this:

```
function someFunc(params = {param1:'value', param2: 'value'}) {
    console.log(Object.keys(params).length);
    console.log(params['param1']);
}
```

Note that this approach requires your argument to be an object and that **given one of the two arguments the other one will not be present in the default object**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Think about it this way. How do you get the default value with the old method?

```
function someFunc(param1, param2) {
    param1 = param1 || 'value';
    param2 = param2 || 'value';

    console.log(arguments.length);
    console.log(arguments[0]);
}

someFunc(); //0 undefined
```

Your best bet is to store the default value in a variable, and compare it in runtime. But that is kind of pointless.